# EF code first won't recognize my DB

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, code-first

The problem I'm facing is the following:

I've been happily developing using code first with Entity Framework 6 and my SQLServer 2014 DB, updating the database, extracting scripts and so far everything worked perfectly. The problem is that suddenly it lost the track of my database and whenever I try to add a new migration it says I have to update the database because it still has pending migrations to apply.

If I look at the database I'm working with it shows everything is there, even the __MigrationHistory table with every migration I'd done registered. Even though I accept code first recommendation and try to update the database. And no surprises here... The first table it tries to create throws an error because it already exists.

Could you please provide me some guidance on this?

Thanks in advance,

P.

Comment: Have you tried the `force` parameter of the `add-migration` command? Check out the other parameters too, type "get-help add-migration -detailed" or "get-help Add-Migration -examples" into your package manager console.

Comment: Yes, I tried everything. I figured it out about an hour ago.
See my own answer :) btw: Thank you so much for your response!

Comment: Ok. Your answer is interesting, what do you mean by "updating the context key"?

Comment: So on the __MigrationHistory table I have the following fields: MigrationId, ContextKey, Model and ProductVersion. It results that the ContextKey field contains the namespace of the configuration of the migrations, so if you change it in your code, Code First won't recognize anything on your DB.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it what was all about.

It happens that I changed the project name and the entire namespaces. The namespace of the migration itself is stored on DB so when I changed the namespace the Code First was unable to find it on the migration table.

Updating the ContextKey for every migration to the current namespace solved my issue.

Thank you for your time.